# c# - Threadpool notifies when complete, not blocking main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

so I am wondering what the best way to call a function when a thread pools execution is complete?

I have to sets of data that are processed via thread pooling. Set A must be completed before Set B. The problem I am having is that I cannot have the main thread wait until Set A is complete before processing Set B. So I need to either fire an event or call a function after the thread count in the pool has been reduced to zero (I am using a Interlocked object to maintain a thread count), I am just wondering what the best way of doing this would be?

Thanks for any help, I hope my question isn't to vague.

Comment: You can get some idea : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I advice you to use **Task** with **ContinueWith()** method. Internaly Tasks use **ThreadPool** class but they are much more flexible. For example:

```
Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Main task"))
            .ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine("Continue task"), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountdownEvent which is based on wait and signal criteria Click [here] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information